# Is there a way to load an Image in Javascript with data retrieved via an HTTP POST?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Is there any means to use AJAX to request an image file via an HTTP POST and then create a new Image with that data in HTML?  Since you can't do this with the IMG tag, is it possible to do it with an Image javascript object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes that is possible.

When your serverscript opens the image files and encodes them as a `base64` string, almost all browsers (except IE7 and below) can handle that. For instance:

```
jQuery('<img>', {
    src: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + someBase64EncodedString
}).appendTo(document.body);
```

A real-world example of this, can be found here: https://github.com/jAndreas/Supply

Comment: This answer is good.  It acknowledges that IE7 below has problems.  I also found this on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28VS.85%29.aspx
"Data URIs cannot be larger than 32,768 characters." Which limits the types of images you can load.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out how to embed base64 encoded data as an image.

Here's an article that walks you through it.

http://danielmclaren.com/node/90

Comment: This is an interesting answer as it applies to earlier forms of IE. +1

Answer (score 1):

If it returns the base64 encoded image data you could probably do it using [data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) and possibly Canvas.

Some "pseudo" code (using PHP and JS+jQuery) to demonstrate what you could do.

Server:

```
$image = new Imagick($imagePath);
echo 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($image);
```

Client:

```
$.ajax({
   method: "post",
   url: "/foo/bar.php",
   success: function (data) {
      $("<img />").attr("src", data).appendTo("#myContainer");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try looking here: http://emilsblog.lerch.org/2009/07/javascript-hacks-using-xhr-to-load.html